# Installing GRUB on a VirtualBox guest - does it affect the host MBR?

Tags: virtualbox, mbr

I am in the process of installing the latest debian stable on VirtualBox (3.1.4), and got to an installation step asking to installing GRUB to the MBR of the disk.  I assume that since this is a "virtual" disk created by VirtualBox, that the MBR for it is isolated from the MBR of the primary disk on the host.  Is this correct?  I had previously been under the (possibly incorrect?) impression that there was 1 MBR per physical primary disk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoted from http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#vdidetails

> Disk image files reside on the host
>   system and are seen by the guest
>   systems as hard disks of a certain
>   geometry. When a guest operating
>   system reads from or writes to a hard
>   disk, VirtualBox redirects the request
>   to the image file.

So it does not affect the host MBR. Only the disk image file.

Answer (score -1):

uhm I think that you can't make changes because you're in a virtual space on your computer, so it can't affect the HDD/SSD, because it's in a closed environment in your laptop.

Comment: You can map the raw HDD into the VM and overwrite it.